# Accuracy of float comparison for cmath.phase results

Tags: python, angle, complex-numbers

Is there any combination of `a`, `b` and  `k` values that could make the following test fail?

```
from cmath import phase, pi

def test_phase(a, b, k):
    c = complex(a, b)
    assert abs(phase(c) - phase(-c)) == pi
    assert phase(c) == phase(k*c)
```

I was expecting some float precision issues with big values but it keeps passing, as far as I tried. Is this accuracy guaranteed and reliable?